# Add local .aar files to Titanium SDK 9 Android module

Tags: android, gradle, titanium

I'm creating an Android module using Titanium SDK 9. I have 2 .aar files that I need to include in my module. According to the documentation you cannot add them to the `lib` directory anymore:

"With Titanium 6.1.1 - 8.3.1, you can also copy AAR (Android Archive) library files to the module's lib directory. However, this is not supported as of Titanium 9.0.0, which requires you to reference these AAR libraries via a build.gradle file instead."

But how do I reference them correctly? The below configuration of my build.gradle file compiles, but when I use the module, I see and error like 'Failed resolution of: Lpolar/com/sdk/api/PolarBleApiDefaultImpl' immediately when I use some of the .aar files classes:

```
implementation files('../../libs/polar-ble-sdk.aar')
implementation files('../../libs/polar-protobuf-release.aar')
// Below 2 lines also compile
// compile files('../../libs/polar-ble-sdk.aar')
// compile files('../../libs/polar-protobuf-release.aar')
implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.4'
implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.1.0'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.5'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
```

The call I'm trying to do in my Titanium project and causes the error:

```
import polar.com.sdk.api.PolarBleApi;
import polar.com.sdk.api.PolarBleApiDefaultImpl;

// and then later on

PolarBleApi api = PolarBleApiDefaultImpl.defaultImplementation(this, 
PolarBleApi.FEATURE_HR);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the libraries at https://github.com/polarofficial/polar-ble-sdk

Using this build.gradle

```
repositories {
       maven { url "https://oss.jfrog.org/libs-snapshot" }
   }


dependencies {
    implementation files('../../libs/polar-ble-sdk.aar')
    implementation files('../../libs/polar-protobuf-release.aar')
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxandroid:3.0.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxjava:3.0.0'
}
```

works fine. No problems using `import polar.com.sdk.api.PolarBleApi;` or auto-completion with Android Studio.
Compiling works fine (but I didn't try the module in Titanium at the end).

**edit:**

- add the build.gradle to your app, too: `platform/android/build.gradle` (same content)
- app: create `/build/libs` and add the libs
- module:

```
    @Kroll.method
    public void create()
    {
        PolarBleApi api = PolarBleApiDefaultImpl.defaultImplementation(TiApplication.getAppCurrentActivity(), PolarBleApi.FEATURE_HR);
        Log.i("Polar", "Version: " + PolarBleApiDefaultImpl.versionInfo());
    }
```

- app:

```
var window = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    title: "Test"
});
var polar = require("ti.polar");

polar.create();

window.open();
```

output: `[INFO]  Polar: (main) [92,92] Version: 2.2.2`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this compiles but with some warnings like `[ERROR] [GRADLE] /polar-ble-sdk-api.jar(polar/com/sdk/api/PolarBleApi.class): warning: Cannot find annotation method 'from()' in type 'IntRange': class file for android.support.annotation.IntRange not found`. And when I use the module from Titanium and call one simple method from the Polar API, the app crashes with: `Error: Failed resolution of: Lpolar/com/sdk/api/PolarBleApiDefaultImpl;`. See my full gradle.build in my original answer.

Comment: I've added the aars in `/build/libs/` inside the app and used the same build.gradle there. If you run into this one: https://github.com/polarofficial/polar-ble-sdk/issues/90 please check the rxandroid page on how to implement it. I've changed my answere to show the full build.gradle. The module and app build and run fine. But I've used the one line you've added in your example

Comment: Hi thanks this is working! I didn't know you had to add the build.gradle and .aar files to the project as well.

Comment: you normally don't have to do that if you use online implementations. They are bundled into the module. A different Ti user was using `adding a local repository into Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/[sdk-version]/android/m2repository  to take the .aar lib` with `api "NAME OF THE LIB"` as a gradle dependency.